# How to optimize select sum() on mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, optimization

I have this SQL, it´s taking about 2,5 seconds to run.

```
select SUM(valorlanca0_.VALOR_PREVISTO) as col_0_0_ 
from CF_VALOR_LANCADO_DETALHADO valorlanca0_ 
inner join CF_VALOR_LANCADO valorlanca1_ on valorlanca0_.ID_VALOR_LANCADO=valorlanca1_.ID_VALOR_LANCADO 
inner join CF_LANCAMENTO lancamento2_ on valorlanca1_.ID_LANCAMENTO=lancamento2_.ID_LANCAMENTO 
inner join CF_ADMINISTRACAO administra12_ on lancamento2_.ID_ADMINISTRACAO=administra12_.ID_ADMINISTRACAO 
inner join CF_EMPRESA empresa13_ on lancamento2_.ID_EMPRESA=empresa13_.ID_EMPRESA 
inner join CF_USUARIO usuario14_ on lancamento2_.ID_USUARIO_CRIOU=usuario14_.ID_USUARIO 
left outer join CF_FORMA_PAGAMENTO formapagam9_ on valorlanca1_.ID_FORMA_PAGAMENTO=formapagam9_.ID_FORMA_PAGAMENTO 
inner join CF_CONTA conta10_ on valorlanca1_.ID_CONTA=conta10_.ID_CONTA 
left outer join CF_FATURA fatura11_ on valorlanca1_.ID_FATURA=fatura11_.ID_FATURA 
left outer join CF_CATEGORIA categoria3_ on valorlanca0_.ID_CATEGORIA=categoria3_.ID_CATEGORIA 
left outer join CF_CENTRO_CUSTO centrocust4_ on valorlanca0_.ID_CENTRO_CUSTO=centrocust4_.ID_CENTRO_CUSTO 
left outer join CF_FAV_FONTE_PAGADORA favfontepa5_ on valorlanca0_.ID_FAV_FONTE_PAGADORA=favfontepa5_.ID_FAV_FONTE_PAGADORA 
left outer join CF_CONTA_CONTABIL contaconta6_ on valorlanca0_.ID_CONTA_CONTABIL=contaconta6_.ID_CONTA_CONTABIL 
left outer join CF_CONTATO contato7_ on valorlanca0_.ID_CONTATO=contato7_.ID_CONTATO 
left outer join CF_MARCA marca8_ on valorlanca0_.ID_MARCA=marca8_.ID_MARCA 
where administra12_.ID_ADMINISTRACAO=406 and lancamento2_.TIPO_CONTA=2 and (conta10_.ID_CONTA in (2060, 404, 405, 4291, 406, 410, 4292, 403, 4355, 402, 407)) and conta10_.TIPO<>9 and lancamento2_.TIPO_TRANSACAO=10 
and (valorlanca1_.SITUACAO in (1)) and ((valorlanca1_.DATA_PREVISTA<='2015-07-22' and valorlanca1_.SITUACAO=1 or valorlanca1_.DATA_BAIXA<='2015-07-22' and valorlanca1_.SITUACAO=3) 
and conta10_.TIPO<>2 or fatura11_.DATA_VENCIMENTO<='2015-07-22' and conta10_.TIPO=2 and valorlanca1_.SITUACAO=1 or valorlanca1_.DATA_BAIXA<='2015-07-22' and conta10_.TIPO=2 and valorlanca1_.SITUACAO=3) 
and ((empresa13_.ID_EMPRESA in (422, 3643)) and usuario14_.ID_USUARIO=574 or empresa13_.ID_EMPRESA in (422, 3643))
```

And this is the explain command

```
1   SIMPLE  administra12_   const   PRIMARY PRIMARY 8   const   1   Using index
1   SIMPLE  empresa13_      range   PRIMARY PRIMARY 8       2   Using where; Using index
1   SIMPLE  lancamento2_    ref     PRIMARY,FKE50FD2D68AC234EC,FKE50FD2D6574FCEF7,FKE50FD2D628D2EAE8,IDXEMPRESA IDXEMPRESA  8   controlese.empresa13_.ID_EMPRESA    225 Using index condition; Using where
1   SIMPLE  valorlanca1_    ref     PRIMARY,FK49527EEB12DDD0DA,FK49527EEBDDD55138,IDX_VL_IDL,IDX_VL_IVL FK49527EEB12DDD0DA  8   controlese.lancamento2_.ID_LANCAMENTO   1   Using where
1   SIMPLE  conta10_        eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 8   controlese.valorlanca1_.ID_CONTA    1   Using where
1   SIMPLE  usuario14_      eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 8   controlese.lancamento2_.ID_USUARIO_CRIOU    1   Using index
1   SIMPLE  fatura11_       eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 8   controlese.valorlanca1_.ID_FATURA   1   Using where
1   SIMPLE  formapagam9_    eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 8   controlese.valorlanca1_.ID_FORMA_PAGAMENTO  1   Using index
1   SIMPLE  valorlanca0_    ref     FK60A3C74EA9A01AC3,IDX_VLD_IDVL FK60A3C74EA9A01AC3  8   controlese.valorlanca1_.ID_VALOR_LANCADO    1   
1   SIMPLE  categoria3_     eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 8   controlese.valorlanca0_.ID_CATEGORIA    1   Using index
1   SIMPLE  centrocust4_    eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 8   controlese.valorlanca0_.ID_CENTRO_CUSTO 1   Using index
1   SIMPLE  favfontepa5_    eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 8   controlese.valorlanca0_.ID_FAV_FONTE_PAGADORA   1   Using index
1   SIMPLE  contaconta6_    eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 8   controlese.valorlanca0_.ID_CONTA_CONTABIL   1   Using index
1   SIMPLE  contato7_       eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 8   controlese.valorlanca0_.ID_CONTATO  1   Using index
1   SIMPLE  marca8_         eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 8   controlese.valorlanca0_.ID_MARCA    1   Using index
```

The biggest table is CF_VALOR_LANCADO(855m records) and CF_VALOR_LANCADO_DETALHADO (860m records).

What I can do to optimize my select?

Comment: Your SELECT isn't bad according to query plan. It looks like you're I/O bound, your hard drive is the issue here. MySQL has to find the records on the drive, which is obviously mechanical and it's slow. Do you use InnoDB and if yes, what's your `innodb_buffer_pool_size` value?

Answer (score 1):

That one hell of  a query :)

You can start by removing the tables that are not used in you WHERE to something like this:

```
select SUM(valorlanca0_.VALOR_PREVISTO) as col_0_0_ 
from CF_VALOR_LANCADO_DETALHADO valorlanca0_ 
inner join CF_VALOR_LANCADO valorlanca1_ on valorlanca0_.ID_VALOR_LANCADO=valorlanca1_.ID_VALOR_LANCADO 
inner join CF_LANCAMENTO lancamento2_ on valorlanca1_.ID_LANCAMENTO=lancamento2_.ID_LANCAMENTO 
inner join CF_ADMINISTRACAO administra12_ on lancamento2_.ID_ADMINISTRACAO=administra12_.ID_ADMINISTRACAO 
inner join CF_EMPRESA empresa13_ on lancamento2_.ID_EMPRESA=empresa13_.ID_EMPRESA 
inner join CF_USUARIO usuario14_ on lancamento2_.ID_USUARIO_CRIOU=usuario14_.ID_USUARIO 
inner join CF_CONTA conta10_ on valorlanca1_.ID_CONTA=conta10_.ID_CONTA 
left outer join CF_FATURA fatura11_ on valorlanca1_.ID_FATURA=fatura11_.ID_FATURA 
where administra12_.ID_ADMINISTRACAO=406 
    and lancamento2_.TIPO_CONTA=2 
    and (conta10_.ID_CONTA in (2060, 404, 405, 4291, 406, 410, 4292, 403, 4355, 402, 407)) 
    and conta10_.TIPO<>9 
    and lancamento2_.TIPO_TRANSACAO=10 
    and (valorlanca1_.SITUACAO in (1)) 
    and ((valorlanca1_.DATA_PREVISTA<='2015-07-22' and valorlanca1_.SITUACAO=1 or valorlanca1_.DATA_BAIXA<='2015-07-22' and valorlanca1_.SITUACAO=3) and conta10_.TIPO<>2 
        or fatura11_.DATA_VENCIMENTO<='2015-07-22' and conta10_.TIPO=2 and valorlanca1_.SITUACAO=1 
        or valorlanca1_.DATA_BAIXA<='2015-07-22' and conta10_.TIPO=2 and valorlanca1_.SITUACAO=3
        )
    and ((empresa13_.ID_EMPRESA in (422, 3643)) and usuario14_.ID_USUARIO=574 or empresa13_.ID_EMPRESA in (422, 3643))
```

Hope it helps abit :)

And one more (the SQL-Server may just do this it self)

```
and ((empresa13_.ID_EMPRESA in (422, 3643)) and usuario14_.ID_USUARIO=574 or empresa13_.ID_EMPRESA in (422, 3643))
```

Is equivalent to just

```
and empresa13_.ID_EMPRESA in (422, 3643)
```

And you can try this change as well (95% sure they are equivalent) - there will be no nested "or", and that sometimes helps performance in my experience.

```
and (   
(valorlanca1_.DATA_PREVISTA<='2015-07-22' and valorlanca1_.SITUACAO=1 
    or valorlanca1_.DATA_BAIXA<='2015-07-22' and valorlanca1_.SITUACAO=3
) and conta10_.TIPO<>2 
or fatura11_.DATA_VENCIMENTO<='2015-07-22' and conta10_.TIPO=2 and valorlanca1_.SITUACAO=1 
or valorlanca1_.DATA_BAIXA<='2015-07-22' and conta10_.TIPO=2 and valorlanca1_.SITUACAO=3
)
```

To:

```
and (   
valorlanca1_.DATA_PREVISTA   <='2015-07-22'   and valorlanca1_.SITUACAO=1 and conta10_.TIPO<>2 
or fatura11_.DATA_VENCIMENTO <='2015-07-22'   and valorlanca1_.SITUACAO=1 and conta10_.TIPO=2 
or valorlanca1_.DATA_BAIXA   <='2015-07-22'   and valorlanca1_.SITUACAO=3
)
```

Answer (score 1):

First, I started by cleaning up the format of your original query to see the correlation of tables.  Then I changed to use aliases to simplify longer table names all over to shorter and came up with this.

```
select 
      SUM(V0.VALOR_PREVISTO) as col_0_0_ 
   from 
      CF_VALOR_LANCADO_DETALHADO V0
         inner join CF_VALOR_LANCADO V1
            on V0.ID_VALOR_LANCADO = V1.ID_VALOR_LANCADO 
            inner join CF_LANCAMENTO L2
               on V1.ID_LANCAMENTO = L2.ID_LANCAMENTO 
               inner join CF_ADMINISTRACAO A12
                  on L2.ID_ADMINISTRACAO = A12.ID_ADMINISTRACAO 
               inner join CF_EMPRESA E13
                  on L2.ID_EMPRESA = E13.ID_EMPRESA 
               inner join CF_USUARIO U14
                  on L2.ID_USUARIO_CRIOU = U14.ID_USUARIO 
            left outer join CF_FORMA_PAGAMENTO F9
               on V1.ID_FORMA_PAGAMENTO = F9.ID_FORMA_PAGAMENTO 
            inner join CF_CONTA C10
               on V1.ID_CONTA = C10.ID_CONTA 
               left outer join CF_FATURA F11
                  on V1.ID_FATURA = F11.ID_FATURA 
         left outer join CF_CATEGORIA C3
            on V0.ID_CATEGORIA = C3.ID_CATEGORIA 
         left outer join CF_CENTRO_CUSTO C4
            on V0.ID_CENTRO_CUSTO = C4.ID_CENTRO_CUSTO 
         left outer join CF_FAV_FONTE_PAGADORA F5
            on V0.ID_FAV_FONTE_PAGADORA = F5.ID_FAV_FONTE_PAGADORA 
         left outer join CF_CONTA_CONTABIL C6
            on V0.ID_CONTA_CONTABIL = C6.ID_CONTA_CONTABIL 
         left outer join CF_CONTATO C7
            on V0.ID_CONTATO = C7.ID_CONTATO 
         left outer join CF_MARCA M8
            on V0.ID_MARCA = M8.ID_MARCA 
   where 
          A12.ID_ADMINISTRACAO = 406 
      and L2.TIPO_CONTA = 2 
      and C10.ID_CONTA in (2060, 404, 405, 4291, 406, 410, 4292, 403, 4355, 402, 407)
      and C10.TIPO <> 9 
      and L2.TIPO_TRANSACAO = 10 
      and V1.SITUACAO in (1)
      and ( (    V1.DATA_PREVISTA <= '2015-07-22' 
             and V1.SITUACAO = 1 
             or  V1.DATA_BAIXA <= '2015-07-22' 
             and V1.SITUACAO=3 ) 
          and C10.TIPO <> 2 
           or F11.DATA_VENCIMENTO <= '2015-07-22' 
          and C10.TIPO = 2 
          and V1.SITUACAO = 1 
           or V1.DATA_BAIXA <= '2015-07-22' 
          and C10.TIPO = 2 
          and V1.SITUACAO = 3 ) 
      and (     E13.ID_EMPRESA in (422, 3643)
            and U14.ID_USUARIO = 574 
             or E13.ID_EMPRESA in (422, 3643) )
```

Now, from this, take a look at your last two AND ( ... ) criteria sections.  You are throwing "OR" conditions in them making them qualify which may NOT be the intent and probably is meant as something different.

First...

```
 and ( (    V1.DATA_PREVISTA <= '2015-07-22' 
         and V1.SITUACAO = 1 
         or  V1.DATA_BAIXA <= '2015-07-22' 
         and V1.SITUACAO=3 )
```

maybe should be explicit about

```
  and ( (    (    V1.DATA_PREVISTA <= '2015-07-22' 
              and V1.SITUACAO = 1 )
         or  (    V1.DATA_BAIXA <= '2015-07-22' 
              and V1.SITUACAO=3 ) 
        )
```

similarly... should any of these be grouped vs the OR falsely including where it shouldn't?

```
  and C10.TIPO <> 2 
   or (    F11.DATA_VENCIMENTO <= '2015-07-22' 
       and C10.TIPO = 2 
       and V1.SITUACAO = 1 )
   or ( V1.DATA_BAIXA <= '2015-07-22' 
        and C10.TIPO = 2 
        and V1.SITUACAO = 3 )
```

Second...

```
  and (     E13.ID_EMPRESA in (422, 3643)
        and U14.ID_USUARIO = 574 
         or E13.ID_EMPRESA in (422, 3643) )
```

Since the last OR condition here is the same as the first, it is thus eliminating the need of the ID_USUARIO = 574 and could be simplified to just...

```
  and E13.ID_EMPRESA in (422, 3643)
```

You have several left-join (functionally identical to "left outer join") not being used in any criteria... remove them including...

```
LEFT JOIN CF_FORMA_PAGAMENTO
left join CF_CATEGORIA 
left join CF_CENTRO_CUSTO 
left join CF_CONTA_CONTABIL 
left join CF_CONTATO 
left join CF_MARCA
```

You are using LEFT-JOIN CF_FATURA fatura11_ and have it in an OR condition which in essence is converting it to an INNER JOIN as you are not allowing for NULL, but an explicit test for the "DATA_VENCIMENTO <= '2015-07-22'"

Simplified down results with (original and/or combinations of criteria)...

```
select 
      SUM(V0.VALOR_PREVISTO) as col_0_0_ 
   from 
      CF_VALOR_LANCADO_DETALHADO V0
         inner join CF_VALOR_LANCADO V1
            on V0.ID_VALOR_LANCADO = V1.ID_VALOR_LANCADO 
            inner join CF_LANCAMENTO L2
               on V1.ID_LANCAMENTO = L2.ID_LANCAMENTO 
               inner join CF_ADMINISTRACAO A12
                  on L2.ID_ADMINISTRACAO = A12.ID_ADMINISTRACAO 
               inner join CF_EMPRESA E13
                  on L2.ID_EMPRESA = E13.ID_EMPRESA 
               inner join CF_USUARIO U14
                  on L2.ID_USUARIO_CRIOU = U14.ID_USUARIO 
            left join CF_FORMA_PAGAMENTO F9
               on V1.ID_FORMA_PAGAMENTO = F9.ID_FORMA_PAGAMENTO 
            inner join CF_CONTA C10
               on V1.ID_CONTA = C10.ID_CONTA 
               left join CF_FATURA F11
                  on V1.ID_FATURA = F11.ID_FATURA 
   where 
          A12.ID_ADMINISTRACAO = 406 
      and L2.TIPO_CONTA = 2 
      and C10.ID_CONTA in (2060, 404, 405, 4291, 406, 410, 4292, 403, 4355, 402, 407)
      and C10.TIPO <> 9 
      and L2.TIPO_TRANSACAO = 10 
      and V1.SITUACAO in (1)
      and ( (    V1.DATA_PREVISTA <= '2015-07-22' 
             and V1.SITUACAO = 1 
             or  V1.DATA_BAIXA <= '2015-07-22' 
             and V1.SITUACAO=3 ) 
          and C10.TIPO <> 2 
           or F11.DATA_VENCIMENTO <= '2015-07-22' 
          and C10.TIPO = 2 
          and V1.SITUACAO = 1 
           or V1.DATA_BAIXA <= '2015-07-22' 
          and C10.TIPO = 2 
          and V1.SITUACAO = 3 ) 
      and (     E13.ID_EMPRESA in (422, 3643)
            and U14.ID_USUARIO = 574 
             or E13.ID_EMPRESA in (422, 3643) )
```

Now, to optimize... The indexes I offer here might significantly help performance via

```
Table                        Index
CF_VALOR_LANCADO_DETALHADO   ( ID_VALOR_LANCADO, VALOR_PREVISTO )
CF_VALOR_LANCADO             ( SITUACAO, DATA_PREVISTA, DATA_BAIXA, ID_VALOR_LANCADO, ID_LANCAMENTO, ID_FORMA_PAGAMENTO, ID_CONTA, ID_FATURA )
CF_LANCAMENTO                ( TIPO_CONTA, TIPO_TRANSACAO, ID_LANCAMENTO, ID_ADMINISTRACAO, ID_EMPRESA, ID_USUARIO_CRIOU  )
CF_ADMINISTRACAO             ( ID_ADMINISTRACAO )
CF_EMPRESA                   ( ID_EMPRESA )
CF_USUARIO                   ( ID_USUARIO )
CF_FORMA_PAGAMENTO           ( ID_FORMA_PAGAMENTO )
CF_CONTA                     ( TIPO, ID_CONTA)
CF_FATURA                    ( ID_FATURA, DATA_VENCIMENTO )
```

Finally, to better see and expose where your criteria are simplified, I would NORMALLY move those with explicit conditions into the respective JOIN / ON conditions, but lets look at a cancelling criteria within...

```
  and V1.SITUACAO in (1)
  and ( (    V1.DATA_PREVISTA <= '2015-07-22' 
         and V1.SITUACAO = 1 
         or  V1.DATA_BAIXA <= '2015-07-22' 
         and V1.SITUACAO=3 )
```

Your first part for SITUACAO IN (1) is immediately going to cancel out the SITUACAO=3 in the (paren) section, but what I think you actually meant to have was...

```
  and V1.SITUACAO in (1)   <--- REMOVE THIS LINE, and add parens below for data/situacao pairs
  and ( (    (  V1.DATA_PREVISTA <= '2015-07-22' 
            and V1.SITUACAO = 1 )
         or  (  V1.DATA_BAIXA <= '2015-07-22' 
            and V1.SITUACAO=3 )
        )
```

As for your other somewhat possible conflicting AND/OR conditions after that, look closer at what you are getting

Answer (score 0):

I'd need to see the indexes you have created on `CF_VALOR_LANCADO_DETALHADO` and `CF_VALOR_LANCADO`, but have you considered a `Composite Index`?  This lets you create an index on more than 1 column.

As a guess, I would look at creating a [multiple column index](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/multiple-column-indexes.html) on 
`CF_VALOR_LANCADO.DATA_PREVISTA` and `CF_VALOR_LANCADO.SITUACAO`

Answer (score 0):

The EXPLAIN on your Query isn't bad at all

Can your run these SQL statements on your MySQL server and post the results here and also post your MySQl server version ?
With these statements we can see if the Query is CPU or I/O bounded.

```
SET profiling = 1;

select SUM(valorlanca0_.VALOR_PREVISTO) as col_0_0_ 
from CF_VALOR_LANCADO_DETALHADO valorlanca0_ 
inner join CF_VALOR_LANCADO valorlanca1_ on valorlanca0_.ID_VALOR_LANCADO=valorlanca1_.ID_VALOR_LANCADO 
inner join CF_LANCAMENTO lancamento2_ on valorlanca1_.ID_LANCAMENTO=lancamento2_.ID_LANCAMENTO 
inner join CF_ADMINISTRACAO administra12_ on lancamento2_.ID_ADMINISTRACAO=administra12_.ID_ADMINISTRACAO 
inner join CF_EMPRESA empresa13_ on lancamento2_.ID_EMPRESA=empresa13_.ID_EMPRESA 
inner join CF_USUARIO usuario14_ on lancamento2_.ID_USUARIO_CRIOU=usuario14_.ID_USUARIO 
left outer join CF_FORMA_PAGAMENTO formapagam9_ on valorlanca1_.ID_FORMA_PAGAMENTO=formapagam9_.ID_FORMA_PAGAMENTO 
inner join CF_CONTA conta10_ on valorlanca1_.ID_CONTA=conta10_.ID_CONTA 
left outer join CF_FATURA fatura11_ on valorlanca1_.ID_FATURA=fatura11_.ID_FATURA 
left outer join CF_CATEGORIA categoria3_ on valorlanca0_.ID_CATEGORIA=categoria3_.ID_CATEGORIA 
left outer join CF_CENTRO_CUSTO centrocust4_ on valorlanca0_.ID_CENTRO_CUSTO=centrocust4_.ID_CENTRO_CUSTO 
left outer join CF_FAV_FONTE_PAGADORA favfontepa5_ on valorlanca0_.ID_FAV_FONTE_PAGADORA=favfontepa5_.ID_FAV_FONTE_PAGADORA 
left outer join CF_CONTA_CONTABIL contaconta6_ on valorlanca0_.ID_CONTA_CONTABIL=contaconta6_.ID_CONTA_CONTABIL 
left outer join CF_CONTATO contato7_ on valorlanca0_.ID_CONTATO=contato7_.ID_CONTATO 
left outer join CF_MARCA marca8_ on valorlanca0_.ID_MARCA=marca8_.ID_MARCA 
where administra12_.ID_ADMINISTRACAO=406 and lancamento2_.TIPO_CONTA=2 and (conta10_.ID_CONTA in (2060, 404, 405, 4291, 406, 410, 4292, 403, 4355, 402, 407)) and conta10_.TIPO<>9 and lancamento2_.TIPO_TRANSACAO=10 
and (valorlanca1_.SITUACAO in (1)) and ((valorlanca1_.DATA_PREVISTA<='2015-07-22' and valorlanca1_.SITUACAO=1 or valorlanca1_.DATA_BAIXA<='2015-07-22' and valorlanca1_.SITUACAO=3) 
and conta10_.TIPO<>2 or fatura11_.DATA_VENCIMENTO<='2015-07-22' and conta10_.TIPO=2 and valorlanca1_.SITUACAO=1 or valorlanca1_.DATA_BAIXA<='2015-07-22' and conta10_.TIPO=2 and valorlanca1_.SITUACAO=3) 
and ((empresa13_.ID_EMPRESA in (422, 3643)) and usuario14_.ID_USUARIO=574 or empresa13_.ID_EMPRESA in (422, 3643));

SHOW PROFILES; # Displays an table with records use it to find your select profile id

SHOW PROFILE ALL FOR QUERY [select profile_id]
```

Most likly statistics has a high Duration and CPU_User in the PROFILE because the large number of JOINS.

MySQL will calculate table permutations to find the best Query plan for executing.

See code below

```
    /* Calculate how to do the join */
thd_proc_info(thd, "statistics");
if (make_join_statistics(this, select_lex->leaf_tables, conds, &keyuse) ||
thd->is_fatal_error)
{
DBUG_PRINT("error",("Error: make_join_statistics() failed"));
DBUG_RETURN(1);
}
```

make_join_statistics() function is a pretty heavy function to run.

Answer (score 0):

My recomendation is you split the query and try to see what is the slower join.

Also there are thing like

```
and **(valorlanca1_.SITUACAO in (1))**
and ((valorlanca1_.DATA_PREVISTA<='2015-07-22' 
  and **valorlanca1_.SITUACAO=1** or valorlanca1_.DATA_BAIXA<='2015-07-22' 
  and **valorlanca1_.SITUACAO=3**)
```

`SITUACAO in (1)` should be `SITUACAO = 1`

But then you have `AND SITUACAO = 3` that doesnt make sense. That and Morten Grue Sørensen comments make me thing you should review your schema.

Also even when `AND OR` have Precedence, puting `( )` help make your query easy to read.

Answer (score 0):

`OR` is sometimes optimized by turning into `UNION`:

```
SELECT ...
    WHERE ((x=1) OR (y=2))
```

-->

```
( SELECT ...
    WHERE (x=1)
)
UNION DISTINCT
( SELECT ...
    WHERE  (y=2)
)
```

(`UNION DISTINCT` is slower than `UNION ALL`, but you may need it for de-dupping.)